# Are there any Catholic Audiobook sharing websites like Librivox?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, internet

Are there any Catholic audiobook websites like [librivox](https://librivox.org/), where christian volunteers from all over the world can read a catholic book, and upload the audiobook to share with all other christians?

---

"LibriVox volunteers read and record chapters of books in the public domain, and make them available for free on the Internet... All recordings... and are also donated into the public domain.

We record books in all languages.

You do not need any prior experience to volunteer for LibriVox, nor do you need to audition or send us samples. All you need is your voice, some free software, your computer, and maybe an inexpensive microphone."

Comment: Librivox itself has tons of Catholic works.

Comment: this is a shopping question, and thus off topic for SE sites.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I have stated in my question that I am asking about the non-profit (audios recorded by volunteers, no purpose of making money from it) websites. I am not asking for commercial ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [CatholicAudioBooks](https://catholicaudiobooks.wordpress.com/) is one such site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a youtube channel called [Optivox](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChhaSGZnwBAnN5QVKjhwwvw/featured) which doesn't seem to have any other online presence than youtube. They have don't have many, though.